# robot_state_publisher can find 'robot' element

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to load a simple urdf file into rviz.
According to the urdf tutorials I need to start the robot_state_publisher and the joint_state_publisher, but when I start the robot_state_publisher on the following file I get an error.

The urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="bobby">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.65 0.72 0.25"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

When I then run the following command:

```
rosparam set robot_description bobby.urdf
rosrun robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher
```

The error that I get is:

```
[ERROR] [1374568528.590558816]: Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
[ERROR] [1374568528.590988619]: Could not generate robot model
[ERROR] [1374568528.591074594]: Failed to extract kdl tree from xml robot description
```

I am using groovy on 13.04
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68203/robot_state_publisher-can-find-%27robot%27-element/) by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-23**:
Can you add the commands you ran?

**Comment by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on 2013-07-25**:
I have added my commands to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your robot needs a name. Replace the first line with something like

```
<robot name="robot">
```

**EDIT:**

The command `rosparam set robot_description bobby.urdf` actually sets robot_description to the string `"bobby.urdf"`. What you want is the actual contents of the xml file there instead. Try instead

`rosparam set robot_description --textfile bobby.urdf`

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on 2013-07-23**:
I tried this, when I do, I get the same error.
(I changed it in my original post)

**Comment by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on 2013-07-25**:
Thank you, this fixed my problem.
I was indeed passing it the filename,

Doe i also have to do this for the join_state_publisher?

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-25**:
It looks to be the same for joint_state_publisher, and I don't imagine the authors would want to have to switch formats for robot_description. It's been a while since I used it though, so I can't tell you for sure.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-25**:
Yip, `robot_description` is the same for every node and has to contain the full XML structure.

**Comment by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on 2013-07-26**:
Ah thanks, everything is clear now.
I interpreted the wiki as meaning the file instead of the text.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-26**:
The node on the other networked machine wants to use `robot_description` and cannot use any local file path. Think big =]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding this as the first line.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on 2013-07-25**:
I have addes this to the code, but the effects are still the same.